# C# formatting text (right align)

Tags: c#

I am a beginner learning C#, I am making a mock shopping list receipt program to manage your shopping. I generate .txt receipt however having problem with right align string here is my code;

```
public static void GenerateNewReciept(Customer customer)
{
    List<ShoppingItems> customerPurchaedItems;
    try
    {
        sw = File.AppendText("receipt.txt");

        //Customer object
        Customer customers = customer;
        //List of all items in list
        List<ShoppingList> customerItems = customer.CustomerShoppingList;
        DateTime todayDandT = DateTime.Now;

        //Making reciept layout
        sw.WriteLine("Date Generated: " + todayDandT.ToString("g", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")));
        sw.WriteLine("Customer: " + customer.FName + " " + customer.SName1);

        for (int i = 0; i < customerItems.Count; i++)
        {
            customerPurchaedItems = customerItems[i].ShoppingItems;
            foreach (ShoppingItems item in customerPurchaedItems)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,0} {1,25:C2}", item.ItemName, item.Price));  
            }
        }

        sw.WriteLine("Total {0,25:C2}", customerItems[0].computeTotalCost());
        sw.Close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FILE NOT FOUND!");
    }
}
```

`sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,0} {1,25:C2}", item.ItemName, item.Price));
sw.WriteLine("Total {0,25:C2}",`  - I want the prices of the items to be right aligned however some items have larger names, meaning when 25 spacing is applied they will be out of place.This is the same with total.

Comment: So what do you want to do when they are out of space? Since you have the boundaries I guess you know what to do in edge cases.

Comment: I dont understand,can you elaborate?

Comment: In the answer you have there is pretty much what I meant. Whenever you make a solution for something think about the cases when the input is not what you would expect and how would you handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually *is* a way to do this with built-in formatting:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            printFormatted("Short", 12.34);
            printFormatted("Medium", 1.34);
            printFormatted("The Longest", 1234.34);
        }

        static void printFormatted(string description, double cost)
        {
            string result = format(description, cost);
            Console.WriteLine(">" + result + "<");
        }

        static string format(string description, double cost)
        {
            return string.Format("{0,15} {1,9:C2}", description, cost);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
>          Short    £12.34<
>         Medium     £1.34<
>    The Longest £1,234.34<
```

Comment: I have implemented the solution just to clarify, when we write {0,15} this means that we right align the string 15 chars we have {1,9:C2} this means that because all the description finish at the 15 position we the add 9 chars. We are aligned since we know where the description ends.

Comment: @dijam Yes, that's right: The "15" means "right justify this field in 15 characters and fill remaining with spaces", and the same applies to the 9. So the description will always take 15 characters and the number will always take 9 - UNLESS the number or string won't fit in that many characters, in which case MORE characters will be used.

Comment: Nice find! +1 to you, and away goes my answer. :-)